# How to access and modify sys_call_table in the linux kernel 3.10

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to edit the sys_call_table to modify some existing system calls and create some of my own. But I found out that linux kernel releases after 2.6 doesn't export this table due to some security reason.

Now i found two solutions on the internet

- download the kernel source, make edit in the table and recompile the kernel kernel.
- Get memory address from /boot/System.map-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 and access it.I tried this with my C code using pointers, but i am getting segmentation fault error.

Is there any other viable way.? What should i do?

Comment: To modify a system call, just modify its source code, and recompile the kernel.

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned the kernel recompile method. I was looking for a solution by which i can manupulate in the live kernel, something that was available before 2.6 version of the kernel.

Comment: Why do you want to write malware?

Comment: NO, i just want to know if there is any alternative provided by linux itself.

Comment: This mechanism was removed because only malware would use it.